# How to deploy a contract and a library together using HardHat

Tags: go-ethereum, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, library, smart-contract

Suppose I have a contract named `MetaCoin.sol`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Tells the Solidity compiler to compile only from v0.8.13 to v0.9.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

// This is just a simple example of a coin-like contract.
// It is not ERC20 compatible and cannot be expected to talk to other
// coin/token contracts.

contract MetaCoin {


    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor() {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) public view returns(uint){
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}
```

which uses `convert` function from library `ConverLib.sol`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

library ConvertLib{
    function convert(uint amount, uint conversionRate) public pure returns (uint convertedAmount)
    {
        return amount * conversionRate;
    }
}
```

Here is my question: Suppose I have to link the library with the smart contract while deploying the contract using hardhat; how can I do this using hardhat?

Truffle uses link function to link library to contract

```
const ConvertLib = artifacts.require("ConvertLib");
const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ConvertLib);
  deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin);
  deployer.deploy(MetaCoin);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution; you have to first deploy the library and then pass the address of deployed library to the contract factory of contract.

```
async function main() {


  const signers = await ethers.getSigners();

  // Library deployment
  const lib = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ConvertLib", { signer: signers[0] });
  const libInstance = await lib.deploy();
  await libInstance.deployed();
  console.log("Library Address--->" + libInstance.address)

  // Contract deployment
  const MetaCoin= await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("MetaCoin", { signer: signers[0], libraries: { DoMath: libInstance.address } });
  const metaCoin= await MetaCoin.deploy();

  await metaCoin.deployed();

  console.log(
    `Lock with 1 ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${metaCoin.address}`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to deploy the Solidity Library that has either a `public` or an `external` function to use it from a smart contract. This library would then sit on a separate address and your smart contract make calls to this address.

In Hardhat, you can pass the addresses of the library to the `getContractFactory` function with an object like this:

```js
const MetaCoin = await this.env.ethers.getContractFactory("MetaCoin", {
  libraries: {
    ConvertLib: "0x...",
  },
});
const metaCoin = await MetaCoin.deploy();
```

[Link to the official documentation of library linking.](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers#library-linking)

**There is a better solution, as long as you can edit the library and change the function's visibility from `public` to `internal`.**

i.e.: `function convert(uint amount, uint conversionRate) internal ....`

Libraries that have `internal` functions **only**, don't have to be deployed separately since the [compiler directly includes the functions in the bytecode of the smart contract](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#libraries).

You can use the `internal` function from the library **the same way** in solidity.

```
import "path/to/ConvertLib.sol";

....

ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
```